# pidgin always show connecting

Tags: xmpp, pidgin

I need to connect pidgin to xmpp server on BOSH.
My xmpp server is ready with http-bind.

But pidgin always shows connecting message and it never connects. If i connect with xmpp without BOSH, it got connected.

My pidgin configuration are below:

```
username : anurag
Domain   : localhost
Resource : bosh
Connect Server :
BOSH URL : http://localhost:5280/http-bind/
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is shown in the Pidgin Debug Window (in the Help menu)?

Comment: (20:08:52) sasl: Mechs found: PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 SCRAM-SHA-1
(20:08:52) jabber: Sending (anurag@localhost/bosh):

   <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='DIGEST-MD5' xmlns:ga='http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth' ga:client-uses-full-bind-result='true'/>

(20:08:58) util: Writing file accounts.xml to directory 
(20:09:49) jabber: RecvBOSH (51): <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
(20:10:49) jabber: RecvBOSH (51): <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>

Comment: Changing hostname from localhost to real hostname, fixes issue. Now it is working